# how to disable template debugging in PyDev

Tags: python, eclipse, debugging, pydev

I'm having an issue with PyDev. When I'm debugging scrips while i'm on admin page, the debugger stops in different places of django suit template.

But I don't need to debug templates so how can I tell Eclipse not to debug templates but to debug only code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can disable those breakpoints by:

1. Open debug perspective
2. Open menu > PyDev > Manage exception breakpoints
3. Edit the related option (suspend on django template render exceptions).

Text has been taken [from here](http://pydev.blogspot.nl/2014/08/pydev-370-pydevpycharm-debugger-merge.html)